# get route direction between two location

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have to get routing direction i.e. all the lat-long location between two location which i provide.
I know below code works for this and give js file in responce.but this code only works when two provided location are not so far. but if two location which are so far suppose between India & Australia then this would be not work and gives nothing in js file.
My code is as below.

```
[NSString* str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", loc1.latitude, loc1.longitude\];
    NSString* str2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", loc2.latitude, loc2.longitude\];

    NSString* urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=%@&daddr=%@&output=dragdir", str1, str2\];]
```

What should i do or I am missing any thing or any filtering is required.Please help me.

-Thanx in advance

Comment: Of course it wi ll not work. It will work only when two distance are not separated by sea.

Comment: In your case it India and Australia there is no direct road between them so it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out first in maps.google.com-> getdirection and check with your location it didn't response because between India and Australia there is no physical root if you check with only land joint country it given correct path so may be it possible same case in iOS..

Comment: Thats what I said to him.. His code is correct but implementing in a wrong way.

Comment: @anonymous agry with your comment

Comment: @anonymous Thanx a lot guys for your quick replies and suppose i want that rout by air any kind of filtering is it possible or not?

Comment: @cocoa Thanx a lot guys for your quick replies and suppose i want that rout by air any kind of filtering is it possible or not?

Comment: I think Google has not figured it out yet. So as my friend Michael Daughterman said: "If you do not find something on Google believe me its a best business opportunity for you to create one." ;-)

Comment: @aakilladhani check out the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144746/road-distance-actual-distance-between-two-places

Comment: @CocoaMatters thnx but this'll give me distance not direction

Comment: @aakilladhani yes i know but there is no such api that give root direction of air.